# How do I select a subset of a DataFrame based on one level of a MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Let

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"v":range(12)}, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["a","b","c"],[1,2,3,4]]))
```

and suppose I want to select only rows with the first level being `a` or `c`:

```
      v
a 1   0
  2   1
  3   2
  4   3
c 1   8
  2   9
  3  10
  4  11
```

I can do:

```
df[df.index.to_frame()[0].isin(("a","c"))]
```

but this creates an intermediate frame which seems like a waste.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you want to use [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```py
df.loc[["a", "c"], :]
```

Comment: this requires an explicit list of acceptable values...

Comment: with [`.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) you can also use integer-location based indexing. Sometimes [`pd.IndexSlice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.IndexSlice.html) comes in handy as well