# How do I select a subset of a DataFrame based on a condition on one level of a MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Similar to [How do I select a subset of a DataFrame based on one level of a MultiIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75796107/850781), let

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"v":range(12)},
                  index=pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(
                      pd.DataFrame({"name":4*["a"]+4*["b"]+4*["c"],
                                    "rank":[x*x for x in range(12)]})))
```

and suppose I want to select only rows with the **second** level `rank` being within 25 from its smallest value for the given **first** level `name`:

```
            v
name rank    
a    0      0
     1      1
     4      2
     9      3
b    16     4
     25     5
     36     6
c    64     8
     81     9
```

This time I have no idea how to do that easily (other than a convoluted combination of `to_frame` and `groupby` - as explained in [How do I select a subset of a DataFrame based on a condition on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75796382/850781)).

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma: it is in the body of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very similar, you can obtain the min rank with reset_index and groupby, then query:

```
# select only one column `v` so we don't copy too many data
min_rank = (df['v'].reset_index('rank')
                   .groupby('name', sort=False)['rank']   # avoid shuffling the dataframe
                   .transform('min')
                   .to_numpy()                            # avoid index alignment
           )

# pass the variable into query string with @
df.query('rank < @min_rank + 25')

# also 
# df.loc[df.index.get_level_values('rank') < min_rank + 25]
```

Output:

```
           v
name rank   
a    0     0
     1     1
     4     2
     9     3
b    16    4
     25    5
     36    6
c    64    8
     81    9
```